# Is there any way to create a global variable by clicking tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a variable by using tkinter button. Due to the fact that a function contains local variables, I typed "global" before the variable. The function assigned to the button's command but does not modify my global variable when pressing. I know that the below code works correctly so the output will be printed out as ".txt" because the print line interpreted before I press the button. Anyways.. it does not modify my variable "filename" and I do not have idea how to solve it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def createFile():
    global filename
    entry1_value=entry1.get()
    filename=entry1_value+".txt"


root=tk.Tk()
root.title("File name selection")
root.geometry("300x200")

label1=tk.Label(root,text="Enter  
file name:",font="Helvetica 12")
label1.place(x=100,y=60) 
entry1=tk.Entry(root,font="Helvetica 12")
entry1.place(x=70,y=85)

button1=tk.Button(root,text="Create file",font="Helvetica 12",command=createFile)
button1.place(x=110,y=110)

print(filename)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put `print(filename)` after `mainloop()`. The fact is that everything till your `mainloop()` will be run once(initially) and code after `mainloop()` will only be run after you close the window.

Comment: I think in this code isnt the error that you are searching for. If I run your code with small changes I can proof that it works. Can you share a little bit more of your original code, so we know where it is missing?

Comment: The code is complete actually, just have a function that prints out `filename` and you will notice its the new `filename`. But yes this current code will give error as `filename` is not defined unless the function is run.